# How to convert the below mentioned xml data into json array in laravel

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Find below the xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <interface-response> <Command>CHECK</Command> <APIType>API.NET</APIType> <Language>eng</Language> <ErrCount>1</ErrCount> <errors> <Err1>User not permitted from this IP address - 113.193.131.41. See http://enom.help/whitelist for details</Err1> </errors> <ResponseCount>1</ResponseCount> <responses> <response> <ResponseNumber>713254</ResponseNumber> <ResponseString>Policy error; unauthorized; user(s)</ResponseString> </response> </responses> <MinPeriod>1</MinPeriod> <MaxPeriod>10</MaxPeriod> <Server>sjl0vwapi08</Server> <Site>eNom</Site> <IsLockable>True</IsLockable> <IsRealTimeTLD>True</IsRealTimeTLD> <TimeDifference>+7.00</TimeDifference> <ExecTime>0.034</ExecTime> <Done>true</Done> <TrackingKey>5baa515b-8e29-4517-b879-05ae68e94f9a</TrackingKey> <RequestDateTime>5/9/2018 3:49:10 AM</RequestDateTime> <debug/> </interface-response>
```

I need to convert the above xml data to json array and pass it to view from the controller.

Find below the conrtroller code:

```
public function test()
{

    $response = Curl::to('https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld=decksys&tld=info&responsetype=xml&uid=userid&pw=password')->get();         


 $data = simplexml_load_string($response);

 $configdata   = json_encode($data);

 $value = json_decode($configdata, true);

 return view('clientlayout.main.test', array('response' =>$response));

 }
```

Find below the view code:

```
{{$response}}
```

The route is given below:

```
Route::get('/test','EnomController@test');
```

suggest a solution solve this and print the data in my view page.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What error did you get?

Comment: This is the error which I get : "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: You have asked the same question again better you should reject accepted answer and continue discussion here only 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270240/how-to-convert-the-json-data-to-the-below-mentioned-format/50271613#50271613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following and that's all.

```
public function test()
{

    $response = file_get_contents('your_xml_url');       


    $data = simplexml_load_string($response);
    $configdata   = json_encode($data);

    return view('clientlayout.main.test', array('response' => $configdata ));

 }
```

Comment: Thank you It's useful. Please help me how to parse this json data and send it to my view . Because when I try to decode this json again I'm facing the same error.

Comment: If you decode it than you can not show  the whole `{{$reponse}}` in the view. You need to specify the specific attribute like `{{$response['Command]}}` .